# Turned off JupyterLab's "auto encapsulation"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I've somehow turned off the feature in JupyterLab where when I highlight something say

```
1,2
```

And press the bracket `(, {, [` it would automatically add the second bracket at the other end.
I don't know what this feature is called, but it's so helpful and I'm crazy annoyed it stopped working.

Restarted already, it still persists.
Can someone help me turn it back on?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [changelog of JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/changelog.html) for 3.1 version, specifically the user-facing changes section, describes that:

> The closing bracket is no longer automatically added by default; the old behaviour can be re-enabled from the menu bar (`Settings` -> `Auto Close Brackets`) or from the `Advanced Settings Editor`.

[image]

This is the seventh option in default JupyterLab 3.1 installations, and second from the bottom on the picture above. For more discussion and to provide **constructive** feedback please go to [jupyterlab issue #5741](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5741).

Comment: Thank you very much!
Sorry for the late reply.
I wasn't able to answer earlier as I had some issues logging in.

Answer (score 5):

For JupyterLab 3.1 onwards, the auto close brackets feature is not the default anymore.

Fortunately this could be easily toggled from the UI, see picture below:

[image]